# A $\subseteq$ B and cluster points

Tags: real-analysis

(a) Show that if *a* is a cluster point of *A*, then it is also a cluster point of *B*.

(b) Give an example of two sets *A* $\subseteq$ *B* and a cluster point *b* of *B* which is not a cluster point of *A*.

I'm still pretty confused on cluster points.

Comment: What is your definition of cluster points?

Comment: @ashK there are many points of S that are arbitrarily close to x

Answer (score 0):

To prove the first part, observe that if $x$ is a cluster point of $A$ then every neighbourhood of $x$ contains some points in $A$ but since every point in $A$ is in $B$, any neighbourhood of $x$ must contain points of $B$ as well.

Take $A=\{0\}$ and $B=[0,1]$. What are the cluster points of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: There would be no cluster points for A and B would have infinitely many?

Comment: @RomanianDraculaIasi Right.